# Spring boot - subtraction inside sortBy (Pageable)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, pageable

Is it possible to subtract two fields(numbers) inside sortBy in pagerequest like this??

```
PageRequest.of(page, size, Sort.Direction.ASC, "price-discount")
```

.
This is error i get..

Sort expression 'price-discount: ASC' must only contain property references or aliases used in the select clause. If you really want to use something other than that for sorting, please use JpaSort.unsafe(…)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creates a new `PageRequest` with **sort direction and properties applied.**

```java
PageRequest.of(page, size, Sort.Direction.ASC, "price", "discount");
```

`OR`

Creates a new `PageRequest` with **sort parameters applied.**

```java
Sort sort = Sort.by(
    Sort.Order.asc("price"),
    Sort.Order.desc("discount"));
PageRequest.of(page, size, sort);
```